# Create ref to a component before then component renderd

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using react-native-google-places-autocomplete for google places auto-complete.
I'm creating a new page to edit the address and I want to use the setAddressText function to insert the last current address before the editing.

I tried to create a ref and store it with redux of the google autocomplete component but since this search bar rendered only when clicking on the edit button the reference hasn't created and I cant use the setAddressText on the ref.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You use either [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) or [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) to create the ref object.  Before calling any methods on it, you must make sure that `myRef.current` has been set.  The easiest way (if your environment is up-to-date enough to support it) is with the [optional chaining operator ?.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
myRef.current?.setAddressText(someText);
```

However I would advise against storing a ref in redux.  As a best practice, it is advised that everything in your redux state [should be serializable](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) — a ref is not.